# Keycloak-How to delete admin user from keycloak server?

Tags: single-sign-on, redhat, keycloak, keycloak-services

I had deleted the admin role from master Relam. Now, I want to create admin role for admin user/master relam. But i am not able to access the Keycloack console UI. I am getting error **"Forbidden
,You don't have access to the requested resource".**

I am new to Keycloak and still learning the basics. Can someone please help me out to restore it?. 
The error page is uploaded at below url

Comment: does Keycloak use embedded default db or external one?

Comment: currently embeded db

Comment: it means that you can restart Keycloak and admin role will be reset along with all the data

Comment: yes i dont want to reset the keycloack as i dont have backup

Comment: you can export the realm, clients, users... now you can't do anything without the admin user anyway